# Process do not gets a pipe from proc_open. lessc - Dynamic Stylesheet language

Tags: php, linux, shell, pipe, less

Here is a source to lessc software, I think it will be helpfull:

```
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc
```

THE PROBLEM

I use lessc in shell simply:

```
lessc file.less
```

and I get a css file output.

I tried to do it by php with proc_open. But when I pipe input file to proc, lessc do not gets it. I have a error (from pipe 1):

```
"lessc: no input files"
```

which is equivalent in shell to (parameter is not passed):

```
lessc
lessc ''
```

My code:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("file", 'path/to/file/foo.less', "r"), 
    1 => array("pipe", "w"), 
    2 => array("file", '/tmp/lessCompiler-errors', "a")
);

$process = proc_open('lessc', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $contents = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);    
    proc_close($process);
}
```

btw. I'm trying avoid using the exec() function.

I will be graceful for any help.
Marcin

Comment: You do know there is a [PHP LESS compiler](http://leafo.net/lessphp/), right?

Comment: Does `lessc` even read from `STDIN`? Descriptorspecs are _not_ arguments.... OTOH, this would be equivalent to `cat file.less | lessc 2> /tmp/lessCompiler-error`....

Comment: @JamWaffles yes, I do. But I have to use lessc. Anyway thank you for advice.

Comment: @Wrikken unfortunately it doesn't. So I can't do that with open_proc? Or mayby is there some trick to workaround?

Comment: Why not simply keep the `STDIN` as the default from the manual, and use `proc_open('lessc /path/to/file.less',...` ? Use `escapeshallarg` just to be sure though.

Comment: And I am going to do that. Just pipes are safer.
Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today, not sure if the solution was valid when you posted the question, but now you can pass '-' as input source to lessc in order to make it read from stdin. So you only have to change one line:

```
$process = proc_open('lessc -', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
```

As it took me some time to figure out all the details here is my code snippet:

```
/* run lessc */
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array( 'pipe', 'r' ),
    1 => array( 'pipe', 'w' ),
    2 => array( 'pipe', 'w' ));
$process = proc_open( 'lessc --no-color -x -', $descriptors, $pipes,
    '/web/less', array( 'PATH' => '/usr/local/bin/' ) );

if( !is_resource( $process ) ) {
    $this->errorMessage( 'Unable to start lessc' );
    exit();
}

/* write generated content */
fwrite( $pipes[0], 'some dynamically generated less code' );
fclose( $pipes[0] );

/* read compiled css */
$css = stream_get_contents( $pipes[1] );
fclose( $pipes[1] );

/* check for errors */
if( $stderr = stream_get_contents( $pipes[2] ) ) {
    $this->errorMessage( "lessc error: {$stderr}" );
    exit();
}
fclose( $pipes[2] );

proc_close( $process );

/* write back */
$this->write( $css );
```

- I had to set `PATH` on debian wheezy, because lessc kept complaining: `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`, see https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3911
- `--no-color` supresses escape codes in the error messages
- `-x` compresses the css